# splitting string into array with a specific number of elements, c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a string which consists number of ordered terms separated by lines (\n) as it shown in the following example: (note, the string I have is an element of an array of string)

```
term 1
term 2
.......
.......
term n
```

I want to split a specific number of terms, let we say (1000) only and discard the rest of the terms. I'm trying the following code :

```
string[] training = traindocs[tr].Trim().Split('\n');
                List <string> trainterms = new List<string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                    if (i >= training.Length)
                        break;
                    trainterms.Add(training[i].Trim().Split('\t')[0]);
                }
```

Can I conduct this operation without using List  or any other data structure? I mean just extract the specific number of the terms into the the Array (training) directly ?? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about LINQ? The [.Take()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) extension method kind of seems to fit your bill:

```
List<string> trainterms = traindocs[tr].Trim().Split('\n').Take(1000).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131450) you can use an overloaded version of the `split` method.

> public string[] Split(    char[] separator,   int count,
>     StringSplitOptions options )
>
> Parameters
>
> separator Type: System.Char[] An array of Unicode characters that
>   delimit the substrings in this string, an empty array that contains no
>   delimiters, or null.
>
> count Type: System.Int32 The maximum number of
>   substrings to return.
>
> options Type: System.StringSplitOptions
>   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries to omit empty array elements
>   from the array returned; or StringSplitOptions.None to include empty
>   array elements in the array returned.
>
> Return Value
>
> Type: System.String[] An array whose elements contain the substrings
>   in this string that are delimited by one or more characters in
>   separator. For more information, see the Remarks section.

So something like so:

```
String str = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I";
            String[] str2 = str.Split(new Char[]{','}, 5, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            System.Console.WriteLine(str2.Length);
            System.Console.Read();
```

Would print: `5`

EDIT:
Upon further investigation it seems that the `count` parameter just instructs when the splitting stops. The rest of the string will be kept in the last element.

So, the code above, would yield the following result:`[0] = A, [1] = B, [2] = C, [3] = D, [4] = E,F,G,H,I`, which is not something you seem to be after.

To fix this, you would need to do something like so:

```
String str = "A\nB\nC\nD\nE\nF\nG\nH\nI";
            List<String> myList = str.Split(new Char[]{'\n'}, 5, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList<String>();
            myList[myList.Count - 1] = myList[myList.Count - 1].Split(new Char[] { '\n' })[0];
            System.Console.WriteLine(myList.Count);
            foreach (String str1 in myList)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(str1);
            }
            System.Console.Read();
```

The code above will only retain the first 5 (in your case, 1000) elements. Thus, I think that Darin's solution might be cleaner, if you will.

Comment: Could you explain some more according to the original post? thank you

Comment: @Qaesar: I have updated my answer. I tested the code and posted what I found. I think it might be a good idea to not remove the post just since this question demonstrates a case of *traditional* (if you will) programming compared to the *more* recent LinQ.

Answer (score 1):

If you want most efficient(fastest) way, you have to use overload of `String.Split`, passing total number of items required.

If you want easy way, use LINQ.

Comment: @ Tilak, is there a difference between the both ways regarding to time consuming? thank you.

Comment: String.Split overload, uses just single loop. LINQ will use 2 loop, one for String.Split, another one for Take. There will be difference (but not a noticeable one).